# how we can use mapbox-android-sdk library in android?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mapbox

How we can use mapbox-android-sdk library for offline Maploading in android and how we can add MBTiles and Vector tiles for draw  offline Map in android ?

I have create a project in which i have use mapbox-android-sdk library by this is load map only in online . Now what should i do for that .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Brad's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27625026/2094275) for how to dynamically save/cache tiles.

Using mbtiles looks to be fairly straightforward and is briefly outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27131050/2094275).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following mapbox android offlical example link to download offline map in mapbox android SDK : 
https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/maps/examples/download-a-simple-offline-map/. In order to give user an option to download a region in map - create a map screen so that user can select a particular location to download. From that selected location as shown in the example we have to pass the top-right point of map (north-east) and bottom-left point of map (south-west) point of map as attribute, so that the particular location will be downloaded. Mapbox recommends to use the offline locations plugin so that it will be downloaded asynchronously. Please refer this link for offline locations plugin : https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/plugins/overview/offline/